# Why do I get an error after changing the root directory of my XAMPP Apache server?

Tags: apache, xampp, webserver

### Context

I'm trying to change the root directory of my XAMPP Apache setup. Currently, the root directory is `/htdocs`. My project folder is named "Real Website", so I want the root directory to be `/htdocs/Real Website` so that I can reference files using the root like I do on my live website (I have to add "Real Website" to the root reference [/Real Website/] before referencing a specific file on my localhost instead of just being able to use "/", like I do on my live server).

To accomplish this, I went into the httpd.conf file (XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf). I edited the following lines from

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Real Website"
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Real Website">
```

I also edited the first directory tags to look as follows:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride all 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After going into a file in my "Real Website" folder after making these changes, I added the line `window.location.href = "/"` in JavaScript to see if it would display the "Real Website" folder. I got this error:

```
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.12 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.0
```

The URL simply shows "localhost", as well.

After checking the error logs, I got this further information:

```
[Mon Aug 09 00:21:55.011957 2021] [authz_core:error] [pid 78225] [client ::1:56063] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/, referer: https://localhost/Real%20Website/index.php
```

### Question

Any idea why I'm getting an "Access forbidden!" error after changing the root directory?

### Things I've Tried

I changed the line "Require all denied" to "Require all granted", as shown below, to no avail (maybe these lines have no impact).

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Additionally, this is the config of the folder directory:

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Real Website">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also tried changing the file permissions on the "Real Website" folder to 777, which didn't work, either.

Could it have to do with the two-word folder name? Could the space between "Real" and "Website" be the issue? I was having trouble with this when trying to add something to .htaccess, so I'm wondering if it's a problem here, too.

Let me know if there are any questions.

Answer (score 0):

if you want people to be able to access the 'real website' directory then you have to grant them access to that directory, something like this...

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Real Website">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include those lines in my post. I already have "Require all granted" listed under those directory tags, which I edited into my post. Any other ideas?

Comment: AllowOverride All - this enables .htaccess files to override your main httpd.conf settings,  .htaccess files slow down apache so it's recommended not to use them if you have access to the main apache config file httpd.conf

Comment: Sure thing. This didn't fix the problem, but I'll take that into consideration.

Comment: I take it you restarted apache to apply the new configuration ?

Comment: Yeah, restarted apache to no avail. However, I found that I hadn't edited my first directory tags, so I edited those to grant access and that seems to have fixed the "access forbidden" error. The only problem is now when I use "/" to reference the root of the server, it still goes to localhost/dashboard instead of going to the index page inside of the "Real Website" folder. So it seems that changing the document root didn't really change anything? Not sure. I'll keep looking into it. If you edit your answer to include changing the first directory tags, I'll approve it.

Comment: You don't want to grant access on the first directory tags, as that's very poor security,  you are telling apache to allow access to all directories. You should always start by restricting access to all directories with the first directory tag and then add additional directory tags for the folders that you want to make public

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know. May I ask what the potential threat is with allowing access to all directories?

Comment: People potentially can gain access to directories that contain files that have nothing to do with the content that you are trying to serve. Its a pretty basic security principle, only grant access to directories that are required.